# Editable FullPath property of a file in the Properties grid - Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, propertygrid, extensibility

I have a project in my VS 2008 solution containing file items. Each item have a standard read only property called "FullPath" in the Properties Grid.

What is the easiest way to make the FullPath property of the Properties Grid editable?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add reference to System.Design
2. Create class

   ```
   public class DllFileNameEditor :
   System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor   {         protected override void InitializeDialog(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
   {
       base.InitializeDialog(openFileDialog);
       openFileDialog.Filter = "Class Library Files (*.dll) |*.dll|All (*.*) |*.*";
       openFileDialog.Title = "Select Class Library File";
   } }
   ```
3. Modify property

   ```
   [Category("Identity")]
   [Description("Dll Location")]
   [EditorAttribute(typeof(DllFileNameEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
   public string DllName
   {
       get { return this.GraphDoc.DllName; }
       set { this.GraphDoc.DllName = value; }
   }
   ```

mgznet.com/EditFullPathProperty.aspx